# Get different JSON responses from PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, cordova

I'm making an app on phonegap.
I'm doing a script that read a ticket code (two queries, first to update the ticket status if exist on the db and second to write a log on another table). This is working fine.

But now, I want to get different responses (Valid or Invalid) with json, but I can't find a way to read the data and showing different responses.

Script on index.html

```
$(function() {
  $("#savedata").click(function() {
    var fcode = $("#code").val();
    var fuuid = $("#uuid").val();
    $("#code").val(" ");
    $("#uuid").val(" ");
     $.ajax({type: "POST", 
        url: "http://phonegap.localhost/test/www/db/update.php",
                  data: ({code: fcode, uuid: fuuid}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: Send
                });    
    });
    function Send(data){    
      document.getElementById('entrada').innerHTML = ("Done!");
    }
  });
```

Update.php

```
<?php
require_once('conndb.php');

$code= $_POST['code'];
$uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
$data=array();

$sql = "SELECT code FROM ticket WHERE code='$code'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){ 
    $sql="UPDATE ticket SET redeem_status= 1 WHERE code = '$code'";
    $resultado=mysql_query($sql);
    $sql2="INSERT INTO log (id, codigo, hora, uuid, valido) VALUES (NULL, '$code', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$uuid', 1)";
    $resultado2=mysql_query($sql2);
    }
    $val['status'] = 1;
    echo json_encode($val);
}else{
    $sql2="INSERT INTO log (id, codigo, hora, uuid, valido) VALUES (NULL, '$code', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$uuid', 0)";
    $resultado2=mysql_query($sql2);
    $val['status'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($val);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code you expect TEXT data but in php-script you sending json. So change dataType to json and fix function Send

Here is simple solution

```
$(function() {
  $("#savedata").click(function() {
    var fcode = $("#code").val();
    var fuuid = $("#uuid").val();
    $("#code").val(" ");
    $("#uuid").val(" ");
     $.ajax({type: "POST", 
        url: "http://phonegap.localhost/test/www/db/update.php",
                  data: ({code: fcode, uuid: fuuid}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: Send
                });    
    });
    function Send(data){    
      if (data.status == 0){
         document.getElementById('entrada').innerHTML = ("Error!");
      }
      else{
         document.getElementById('entrada').innerHTML = ("Done!");
      } 
    }
  });
```

Comment: When i change the dataType dont return anything.

Comment: add 
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

to the beginning of php-script

Comment: before "if (data.status == 0)" put "console.log(data)" and show it

Comment: Is not returning anything

Comment: probably you have an error in your Update.php script. Check logs

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new PHP page which is reading data in your DB and then returning it as JSON (as you're doing right now) and bind an action on a button for example with jQuery in your phonegap app to launch an Ajax call to this page then on success, you use a function to apply what you receive on the smartphone screen.

Comment: I tried something like that with a second function but is not working

Comment: I cant find a way to ready the json, thats the issue im having